# UITableView elements cached

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, memory-management

I have a UITableView with 1000 elements. Before loading it for the first time Instruments shows 2.20MB of bytes still alive. After charging it shows 4.82MB. When I release the memory and return to the previous state it shows 4.71MB. But now when I load the same table, Instruments shows 4.82MB again. Is the structure of the UITableView stored in the cache? If yes, is there any way to release this memory?

My table construction:

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"SearchResult";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault   reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
    } 

    if(!isSomeStateSearching) cell.textLabel.text = [[[contentSomeState objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectForKey:@"rowValues"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    else
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = [searchedAllContent objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    UIView *v = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];
    v.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:188/255.0 green:57/255.0 blue:25/255.0    alpha:1.0];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = v;

    UIImageView *arrow = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"seta_navegacao"]] autorelease];
    cell.accessoryView = arrow;

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you use the reuse mechanism of your `UITableViewCell` correctly, right?

Comment: Yes, I will add to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You should be allocating and adding cell subviews only when initialising a new cell. As it stands you are creating a new view and image view every time a cell is reused. This is why your table is taking up so much memory.

Comment: The problem is not taking so much memory. The problem is that the memory is not releasing in the end. I can comment the view and the imageview in the end of the code and the problem continues.